# converting grammar (written in ANTLR) of a language into formal language/mathematical notations

Tags: antlr, formal-languages, formal-methods

In my current project, my boss has assigned a job of expressing a  grammar (written in  ANTLR) of domain specific language into formal language/notations. For instance, the following is a small code snippet of grammar.

```
     vocabSpec : 'resources' ':' resources_def ;   // Resource definition 

     resources_def :
          'sensors' ':'   (sensor_def)+   // Sensor definition
          'actuators' ':' (actuator_def)+  // Actuator definition       
         ;

     sensor_def:
        CAPITALIZED_ID  
        (sensorMeasurement_def ';')* ;

      sensorMeasurement_def : 'generate' lc_id ':'  CAPITALIZED_ID ;

    // Actuator definition : Actuator name, actions and its parameters 

      actuator_def: CAPITALIZED_ID  (action_def ';')* ;

      action_def: 'action' CAPITALIZED_ID '(' (parameter_def)? ')'  ;

      parameter_def :  lc_id ':'  CAPITALIZED_ID (',' parameter_def )?  ;

      lc_id: ID ;

      ID  : 'a'..'z'  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' )* ;

      CAPITALIZED_ID: 'A'..'Z' ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' )*;
```

As per my knowledge, ANTLR grammar of any language is itself a formal specification. I have no idea -- How can I specify this grammar is formal way. Could you please give me pointers for writing the above grammar into formal specification/mathematical notations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an ANTLR grammar is a formal system.  Based on this, you can just declare victory with a straight face.

He probably wants something other than ANTLR syntax. And, rightfully so, the annotations in the ANTLR grammar for building trees, etc, just confuse the issue, as do the various lookaheads.  So, in your shoes, I'd remove all the annotations, and probably recast the grammar into IEEE EBNF (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).  And you can point him to that web page, and declare you have a "pure context free grammar".

Comment: Many thanks Ira Baxter for your  pointer. Could you please provide me the pointers  about -- how could I specify the above grammar into mathematical notions ?

Comment: Why do you think those aren't mathematical notions?

Comment: I believe that the above mentioned grammar is embedded with keywords (such as 'resources', 'action', 'generate'). They are not general enough that can be used for designing other domain specific languages. Kindly correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: Figure out what question you are asking.  You wanted "a more mathematical version of ANTLR"; I told you *one* way to get that.   A question about "how does the keyword 'resource' have anything to do with designing DSLs" is *so* far away from the original question that I'm simply going to ignore it.

Comment: Sorry Ira Baxter, I do not agree with you. I have already expressed my  interest in "mathematical notions".

Comment: @PankeshPatel What does that actually *mean*?

Comment: Can you point to some sources comparing ANTLR grammar vs BNF vs EBNF? I am thinking of using ANTLR grammar to specify a DSL for a paper related to formal languages. Should I rewrite it in BNF or is ANTLR also well accepted by the research folks?

Comment: All a research paper needs is a clear specification of the grammar.  You can use any formalism (ANTLR is fine, so is classic EBNF) as long as you say what your notation is.   As practical issue, people tend to use EBNF because the ANTLR version contains a lot of unnecessary detail for understanding a technical paper; for instance, nobody cares what lexemes look like under the assumption that they are easily specified.  Even the EBNF often used is abbreviated;  all you want in the paper is what is necessary to understand it. ...

Comment: ....  I suggest you implement your DSL using ANTLR (or whatever),  and then write abbreviated EBNF to specify the essential features.  Remember, the more space your grammar takes up in the paper, the less room you have to explain why it has what it has, and why those concepts are interesting, and what results you have.    These are the ideas the technical reader really wants.